# Persist database after ETL OrientDB

Tags: docker, orientdb, database-backups, orientdb-etl

I am using OrientDB through the docker image. I import all the data I need from CSV files using ETL Loader. However, after I restart docker-compose all the data gets lost. How can I persist the current database? Should I use some database import/export or backup techniques?

OrientDb docker-compose file:

```
 orientdb:
      image: orientdb:latest
      ports:
        - "2424:2424"
        - "2480:2480"
      environment:
        ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'rootpwd'
      volumes:
        - /opt/orientdb/config:/opt/orientdb/config
        - /opt/orientdb/databases:/opt/orientdb/databases
        - /opt/orientdb/backup:/opt/orientdb/backup
        - ./import_json:/orientdb/bin/import_json
        - ./dataset_csv:/orientdb/bin/dataset_csv
```

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: It's version 3.0.4.